# Python multiple if else function and return

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Is this possible on python ?

```
def NearSourceFactor(seismic_source_distance,seismic_source_select): 
    Na = 0 
    if (seismic_source_distance <= 2) and (seismic_source_select == "A"):
        Na == 1.5
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 5) and (seismic_source_select == "A"):
        return Na == 1.2
    elif (seismic_source_distance > 10) and (seismic_source_select == "A"):
        return Na == 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 2) and (seismic_source_select == "B"):
        return Na == 1.3
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 5) and (seismic_source_select == "B"):
        return Na == 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance > 10) and (seismic_source_select == "B"):
        return Na == 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 2) and (seismic_source_select == "C"):
        return Na == 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 5) and (seismic_source_select == "C"):
        return Na == 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance > 10) and (seismic_bldg_geometry == "C"):
        return Na == 1.0

Na = NearSourceFactor(seismic_source_distance,seismic_source_select)
```

`seismic_source` is 10 and `seismic_source_select` = B but unfortunately the answer is = "None"

I'm expecting the answer is 1.0

Comment: None of your conditions match if `seismic_source` is 10. What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: I’m expecting the answer should be Na = 1.0

Comment: *Why* are you expecting that?

Comment: You dont have any if statments catching for sesimic_source = 10, and also what you are returning is Na == 1.0 which would return a boolean value.

Comment: @khelwood given is 10 and B, it should return to me in Na = 1.0

Comment: @AlbertPamonag But none of your conditions expresses that possibility.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, this is possible in python. You just need to add the elif statement that matches your requirements.

Comment: Do yo expect the function to return an integer?

Comment: I see, do you have any suggestion to improve my condition?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use `>= 10` instead of just `> 10`?

Comment: @Rohi yes, i expect integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def NearSourceFactor(seismic_source_distance,seismic_source_select): 

    if (seismic_source_distance <= 2) and (seismic_source_select == "A"):
        return 1.5
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 5) and (seismic_source_select == "A"):
        return 1.2
    elif (seismic_source_distance > 10) and (seismic_source_select == "A"):
        return 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 2) and (seismic_source_select == "B"):
        return 1.3
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 5) and (seismic_source_select == "B"):
        return 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance >= 10) and (seismic_source_select == "B"):
        return 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 2) and (seismic_source_select == "C"):
        return 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance <= 5) and (seismic_source_select == "C"):
        return 1.0
    elif (seismic_source_distance > 10) and (seismic_bldg_geometry == "C"):
        return 1.0

Na = NearSourceFactor(seismic_source_distance,seismic_source_select)
```

I fixed it so it would do what you want, but please be aware of the following things :

a) There is no reason to configure a variable which you want to return, all you need to do is return the value (return 1, for example)

b) When writing Na == 1.0, you are actually comparing and receiving a boolean value.

c) Try and see if you can change the logic to not have so many if statments (It seems like you have a default value of 1, so you can put everything in a else statment for example)

Comment: Cool, Thank you so much. This is very helpful.